# Magnetic stripe reader on Debian

Tags: linux, drivers, usb

I have recently aquired a USB magnetic stripe card reader. When used on Windows, I swipe a card, it acts as a keyboard and types out whatever is on the magstripe.

However when used on Linux (Ubuntu on my laptop, Debian on my RPi), I swipe a card, the green LED goes off (the same happened when I deliberately chose a random driver for it in Windows, so I assume it is a driver issue), and there is no input at all when a USB keyboard works fine on the same system.

lsusb shows this device as `ID 1234:5678 Brain Actuated Technologies`, with the product called `GIT USB READER`.

Would appreciate it if anyone can guide me in the right direction with which drivers I need to install (maybe different HID ones?)

Comment: Worth adding the relevant section of the `lsusb -v` output, and advise what Windows recognises the device as (just a generic usb keyboard, or something more specific?).

Comment: Check http://www.linux-usb.org if you find that reader in the list of supported devices.

Comment: @steve, http://pastebin.com/CnqskFit is the `lsusb -v` section, and it appears as both an HID Keyboard Device using keyboard.inf/kdbhid and a USB Input Device using input.inf/HidUsb.

Comment: @ott, the device ID being 1234:5678 isn't extremely helpful as such a device doesn't seem to exist. Not entirely sure of the brand/product except from the `GIT USB READER` tag